# Golan and mongo query in mgo

Tags: mongodb, go

So I have this mongo db query which works fine:

```
db.levels.aggregate([{
         $match: {
                  "_id": {$lt: ObjectId("56410480f91e505237902dae")}
         },
},     
        { $group: 
            {             
                 "_id": {"title": "Level 11"},
                 "totalAmount": { $sum: "$rewardCoins"}
            }
        } 
])
```

It should get all rows before give id and based on rewardCoins calculate sum.

Now with mgo in golang I'm strugling to get this working... I'm going with pipe but my resultset is empty.

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$lt": level.ID}},
        "$group": bson.M{"_id":"$title", "totalReward": bson.M{"$sum": "$rewardCoins"}}}})

    res :=[]bson.M{}

    pipe.All(&res)
```

What I'm doing wrong here ? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is how my simple rows look like in db:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5613f5ad153678d113d01f4a"), "title" : "Level 1", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(1000) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56159796153678d113d02d60"), "title" : "Level 2", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(50000) }
```

Comment: The '$group' have different keys, not sure is a typo.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini yeap it's a typo thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

The structure in Go isn't the same as in the other language. If you hit Enter after every brace or comma, add commas where Go wants them, and run `go fmt`, you get one `bson.M`:

```
pipe := c.Pipe(
    []bson.M{
        {
            "$match": bson.M{
                "_id": bson.M{
                    "$lt": level.ID,
                },
            },
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id": "$title",
                "totalReward": bson.M{
                    "$sum": "$rewardCoins",
                },
            },
        },
    },
)
```

Another way to see it is that there's no `}, {` before `$group` in the Go, whereas there is in the JSON-y version.

Indenting this way seems like a good idea in general; the eyes can get lost in a sea of brackets otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  However query looks fine, but I'm not getting results now, with pipe.All I get "Panic recovery -> result argument must be a slice address" and if I go with pipe.One(&res) result is empty map[] and it shouldn't be

Comment: Sorry, I don't know; not a mgo/Mongo guy just perused the question and noticed the code didn't seem to quite match.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but looks like only one possible problem in your query is the type of `level.ID`. If it is string you should convert it to `ObjectID` with `bson.ObjectIdHex(string)` function.

**Update 2**

Took example documents but made custom `_id`s to be sure that they are in order. If on your database this code doesn't work that mean your documents `_id` are not in order. I.e. you've added 'Level 11' before 'Level 1', or different Levels were added on different machines as `ObjectID` has timestamp and machine ID in it and shouldn't be used as sorting field to be honest. As someone suggested in your another question - just add `level` numeric field and `$match` by it to be sure that you are selecting right documents.

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://souser:123456@ds055855.mlab.com:55855/catalog")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("catalog").C("levels")

    /*
    Database structure
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56410480f91e505237902dab"), "title" : "Level 8", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(25)}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56410480f91e505237902dac"), "title" : "Level 9", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(40)}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56410480f91e505237902dad"), "title" : "Level 10", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(55)}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56410480f91e505237902dae"), "title" : "Level 11", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(70)}
    */
    pipe := c.Pipe(
        []bson.M{
            bson.M{
                "$match": bson.M{
                    "_id": bson.M{
                        "$lt": bson.ObjectIdHex("56410480f91e505237902dae"),
                    },
                },
            },
            bson.M{
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id": bson.M {
                        "title": "Level 11",
                    },
                    "totalAmount": bson.M{"$sum": "$rewardCoins"},
                },
            },
        },
    )
    result := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&result) // [map[_id:map[title:Level 11] totalAmount:120]]
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d", result[0]["totalAmount"]) // 120
}
```

Comment: level.ID is bson.ObjectId

Comment: @Splendid I've added the code that works as expected in case if your go code properly describes your mongo documents structure. If your documents look different, please update the question with sample document structure.

Comment: well this works but not good since I don't get total and I get all records before. In db my rewardCoins is defined like "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(50000) not sure is that making some difference ?

Comment: @Splendid updated again but pretty sure it's something with your DB and not Go.